# ASP.NET Identity, difference between Claim and LoginInfo

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, asp.net-identity

Actually I am working on a Custom authentication component using OWIN ASP.NET Identity. So far I was able to customize all the steps and implement the following interfaces:

- **IUserStore**

  - Used to find and create Users
- **IUserPasswordStore**

  - Used to validate Password
- **IUserClaimStore**

  - Used to manage claims
- **IUserLoginStore**

  - Used to manage Logins

***What is not clear to me is the difference between a Claim and a Login.
Example with Twitter.***

When a User login with Twitter I first verify if the User account is allowed to Login with Twitter:

```
/// Get the external Login
ExternalLoginInfo info = await authenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
/// Create the Claim
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
   new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, info.DefaultUserName)
};
/// create the identity
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

At this point I can do the following checks:

1) Check if the User is allowed to Login with Twitter

```
CustomUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(info.Login);
```

2) Check if the User has already a Claim associated to Twitter

```
IList<Claim> claimsUser = userManager.GetClaims(user.Id.ToString());
```

What is the difference between the two? If I understand right, for each **Login Session** the User will always use the same LoginInfo but it may get a different Claim object from Twitter, or both object are universal per User?